# Any Data Validation to force user to allow only Case Insensitive Alphabets only?

Tags: excel, validation

I want a cell to throw Error "`Only enter alphabets. Not allow special characters and Numbers"`. Even If I Enter a DOT `.`, it should throw a stop error msg.

Is data validation possible?

Example:

```
ANIL KUMAR .P is ERROR
and ANIL KUMAR P is RIGHT
```

**NOT Allowed:**

Special Characters:

```
"!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"
```

Numbers: `0123456789`

Comment: create an alphabetic only regex based udf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom DV formula like:

```
=AND(MIN(CODE(MID(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))),1)))>64,MAX(CODE(MID(UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))),1)))<91)
```

make sure to uncheck the 'Ignore blank' option.